# how to search for keywords in strings

Tags: java, search, compare, contains, matcher

I need to do some keywords search and print if true.
works fine if i am comparing in order. but i want to

compare the following cases and expect them to be true.

do some java programming = true

some java = true

do programming = true

and finally most importantly

programming java = true

programming java some do = true

I need to return true for all the cases mentioned above but so far it only works for case 1 and 2

```
public class Examples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] given = new String[20];
        given[0]  = ("do some java programming");
        given[1] = ("do some grocery shopping");
        given[2] = ("play soccer at the west field");
        String input = new String();
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the string to compare");
        input[0] = userInput.nextLine();
        for (int i=0; i <20; i++){
        if(given[i].contains(input))
        {
            System.out.println(given[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you open to other solutions which is cleaner than yours? like swtich stetment

Comment: yes i am and also i need to edit my input. It is string not  string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this Regex will be your friend.

Here's some working code to play with:

```
String[] matches = input[0].split(" ");           
for (int i=0; i <3; i++){
  for(String s: matches){
    if(given[i].contains(s))
      System.out.println(given[i]);
      break;
     }      
  }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated for your input! This really helped me get what i want much easier. Plus thanks to everyone else for their input they were also helpful

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow! Don't forget to upvote good answers, and verify the answer you found most helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Outline of one way to solve this:

Each string in `given` should be converted to a `Set<String>` that is a set of all the words in the string.  Use `split()` on each string to get the words, then go through the list of words and add each word to the `Set`.

For each input string, use `split()` to split it into words, then create any kind of collection (a `Set<String>` will work, but creating a `List<String>` by using [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) works too.

You can then see if the collection of words from the input is a subset of the set of words in each `given` string by using a `Set`'s [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-) method.

(Note that you'll have to make sure the input string isn't the empty set first.  Also, if the input string has more than one occurrence of any word, this approach won't catch that, without some extra logic.)

Comment: why not use Switch statement which is gonna be cleaner?

Comment: @ajb I dont know if converting set of given would work for an array list of objects. I am looking forward for a bigger assignment in which i store objects in arrayList and search for title which is an instant variable for the class and print all the objects that matches the keyword for title.

Comment: @Omer I was thinking you'd need an `ArrayList<Set<String>>` where the `ArrayList` would have size 3 (in your example) and each element would be the set of keywords in one string.  I'm not sure I understand what your future requirements are.  Anyway, I'm hoping that at least some of the ideas in the answer will be helpful.

Comment: @ajb I think this give me a good idea to get started. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Split the given lines and store it in a List.
Again split the input line and compare word by word.
Below is the code snippet

```html
public class StringCompare
{
    public static final String delimiter = " ";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String[] given = new String[20];
        given[ 0 ] = ( "do some java programming" );
        given[ 1 ] = ( "do some grocery shopping" );
        given[ 2 ] = ( "play soccer at the west field" );

        List< List< String >> listLineAsWords = new ArrayList< List< String >>();
        
        //split each line and store it as list.
        for ( String line : given )
        {
            if ( line == null )
                break;
            listLineAsWords.add( Arrays.asList( line.split( delimiter ) ) );
        }

        
        //Write your own logic to get the input line
        String inputLine = "programming java";
        if ( compareLine( inputLine, listLineAsWords ) )
            System.out.println( "The input line is part of given lines" );
    }

    private static boolean compareLine( String inputLine, List< List< String >> listLineAsWords )
    {
        if ( inputLine == null )
            return false;
        List< String > words = Arrays.asList( inputLine.split( delimiter ) );
        for ( List< String > listOfWords : listLineAsWords )
        {
            boolean isPartOfLine = true;
            for ( String word : words )
            {
                if ( !listOfWords.contains( word ) )
                {
                    isPartOfLine = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPartOfLine)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just started contributing StackOverFlow, so a upvote will be great. @Omer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, yet it needs some changes

**First**, since in your sample code you have `3` case, it is best to  define your given **array length 3**.

```
String[] given = new String[3];
```

Note: for more cases, you can define bigger array length; for example, if you will add other 2 cases, your array length is `5`

For all reference types, the default value is null if you have array length more than you need.

[read more about it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

**Second**, in your if statement, you want to check if input contains given element of array or not

```
if (input.contains(given[i])) {
```

**code**:

```
    String[] given = new String[3];
    given[0] = ("do some java programming");
    given[1] = ("do some grocery shopping");
    given[2] = ("play soccer at the west field");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the string to compare");
    String input = userInput.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < given.length; i++) {
        if (input.contains(given[i])) {
            System.out.println(given[i]);
        } else {
          //  System.out.println("do nothing");
        }
    }
```

**output**:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Modify as below assuming everything else is fine

```
//here initialize 'given' array
//get the user input in a string that is 'input[0]' in your case
int count = 0; 
for (String s : given) {
   if (s != null && s.matches(input[0])) {
      //it matches and print it
   } else {
      //either it's not a match or the 'given' array has a null at this index
   }
   count++;
}
```

I must say, get the user input in a string. I don't understand why you have it in `input` array.